# How to change the log file in the server in MobileFirst 6.3

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

We are using mobilefirst 6.3 in a production  Websphere liberty profile.

Is there a way in mobilefirst to change the default log file, without using some custom java functions to log? we want to have the logs from our adapters separately from the server logs.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to IBM MobileFirst Platform, but to WebSphere Liberty which MFP is deployed to. It's an important distinction to make - all logging goes through the hosting application server, not through MFP.

To my knowledge and after reading the Liberty documentation - this is not possible in a straight-forward, official, capacity.

What you could perhaps do is:

1. Understand from the messages.log file which logs you'd like to filter. All log lines begin with a specific tag like `FW123456`
2. Write a script that will scan the messages.log file for occurrences of required tag
3. Copy the specific log line and save it in a different file

Comment: checking the messages.log, this are 2 examples of a our log in the same adapter and they have different tags:

[5/8/15 14:22:05:592 ART] 000004da ht.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation I submitNotification

[5/8/15 14:21:26:827 ART] 000001c5 ht.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation I submitNotification

Comment: Then perhaps you need both tags.